# Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: FileName (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, maven, servlets, intellij-idea, filenotfoundexception

I get the error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: AuthKey_7RHM5B8NS7.p8 (No such file or directory)", the file is clearly in my directory and I am using the relative path for the file.  Here is my projects directory.

Project directory Image

[image]

```
final ApnsClient apnsClient = new ApnsClientBuilder()
    .setApnsServer(ApnsClientBuilder.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST)
    .setSigningKey(ApnsSigningKey.loadFromPkcs8File(new File("AuthKey_7RHM5B8NS7.p8"),
            "GL87ZNESF6", "7RHM5B8NS7"))
    .build();
```

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: Use: File f = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getFile());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are trying to fetch file from resource folder hence you need to specify path for that.

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/AuthKey_7RHM5B8NS7.p8").getFile());
```

or to get the URL

```
URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("AuthKey_7RHM5B8NS7.p8");
File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the [`ApnsSigningKey.loadFromPkcs8File`](http://relayrides.github.io/pushy/apidocs/0.10/com/turo/pushy/apns/auth/ApnsSigningKey.html#loadFromPkcs8File-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method but instead use the [`loadFromInputStream`](http://relayrides.github.io/pushy/apidocs/0.10/com/turo/pushy/apns/auth/ApnsSigningKey.html#loadFromInputStream-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

The reason is that you are using a *resource* - and if you build a JAR file from your code, as is often done, your resource will be inside the JAR file and you will not be able to get a `File` object that points to it.

Code:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/AuthKey_7RHM5B8NS7.p8");

final ApnsClient apnsClient = new ApnsClientBuilder()
    .setApnsServer(ApnsClientBuilder.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST)
    .setSigningKey(ApnsSigningKey.loadFromInputStream(in, "GL87ZNESF6", "7RHM5B8NS7"))
    .build();

in.close();
```